# Using sed to replace a word of a line on basis of finding that line on first two words of that line in a file

Tags: regex, sed

After going through and trying numerous articles regarding unix sed cmd and regular expressions online,i still not able to achieve what i wanted. Please help me to achieve this.
I have a file Gemfile,in this i want to find a line on basis of first two words and replace another word on that line.How can i achieve this in ubuntu with sed cmd.
My Gemfile is like this:-

```
gem 'retryable'
gem 'roo'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '8.6.5'
gem 'music', branch:'mae-45124', git: vhl_repo('mymusic')
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0'
```

In this file i want to first search a line using first two words i.e. gem 'retryable'
gem 'roo'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '8.6.5'
gem 'music', branch:'mae-45124', git: vhl_repo('music')
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0' and then replace the value of branch given i.e. for eg in this case **'mae-45124'** 
I have tried using this cmd bu this is giving this error ->

```
sed -i -e "/^gem \'music\'.*/s/mae-45124/mae-44444" Gemfile
```

Error coming is :-

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unterminated `s' command
```

I want to change this line from:- 
gem 'music', branch:'mae-45124', git: vhl_repo('music') 
to
gem 'music', branch:'mae-44444', git: vhl_repo('music')

Please tell me how can i achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put another '/' after 44444, that's what the error about.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 sed -ir "/^gem 'music'.*/s/mae-45124/mae-44444/" Gemfile
```

You don't need to escape `'` since you are using `"` around them.
<strike>In some situation you might need to escape `-`.</strike>

And your own solution don't have the last '/', which is to finish the `s` command.

Comment: it's also working without escaping  '-'  like:-
sed -i "/^gem 'music'/s/mae-44554/mae-43535354554/" Gemfile

Comment: @POW Outside of a bracket expression, `-` is not a special regex metacharacte, it is a simple `-` char.